# Mixing server models in Hyper-V Failover Cluster

Tags: hyper-v, failovercluster

Does anyone have experience with a heterogeneous blend of servers in a Hyper-V failover cluster?  We have a cluster with blended generations of Proliants (DL360 G9s and DL360 G10s), and I'm considering introducing Dell servers into the mix due largely to availability and pricing.  Is this a bad idea, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it and it will work. You will need to have processor compatibility option enabled to migrate VMs between hosts. If you buy the same Dell servers, I would recommend you to split them into 2 clusters. Speaking about shared storage, in theory you should be able S2D, but you can face issues. S2D shines in the supported configurations.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/storage-spaces-direct-overview

As another alternative, you can use StarWind VSAN.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san

Of course, the easiest option (in terms of configuration) would be to use SAN.